# What makes the difference in "grad attribute" in the following context?

Tags: pytorch, shortcut, autograd

Consider the following two contexts

```
with torch.no_grad():
  params = params - learning_rate * params.grad
```

and

```
with torch.no_grad():
  params -= learning_rate * params.grad
```

In the second case `.backward()` is running smoothly and in the first case it is giving the

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

What is the reason for this as it is normal to use `x-= a` and `x = x - a` interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  `x -= a` and `x = x - a` [*cannot* be used interchangeably](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__isub__): The latter creates a new tensor that is assigned to the variable `x`, while the former performes an *in place* operation.

Therefore with

```
with torch.no_grad():
  params -= learning_rate * params.grad
```

everything works fine in your optimization loop, while in

```
with torch.no_grad():
  params = params - learning_rate * params.grad
```

the variable `params` gets *overwritten* with a *new* tensor. Since this new tensor was created within a `torch.no_grad()` context, this means that this new tensor has `params.requires_grad=False` and therefore does not have a `.grad` attribute. Therefore in the next iteration torch will complain that `params.grad` does not exist.